# How to force the Issue ID inside Issue tracking list to have certain format

Tags: 2013, list, development, issue-tracking

I want to create a new issue tracking list inside my team site. currently the issue will get a unique ID such as 1, 2, 3. but i need the ID to have a per-defined format. i am trying to achieve the following :-

1. Site Admin, enter a string , such as "ABC".
2. then new Issue item will get its unique ID as ABC-01 ,ABC,-02 , etc..

So can anyone adivce how i can achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to add new column "Issue ID" in your list. Then you can use SharePoint designer workflow or event receiver to create this unique string and to update in "Issue ID"  column.

Steps:

1. Create a column "Issue ID" in your Task List
2. Now go to SharePoint Designer, Create a workflow for task list and set it to run automatically when Item is added
3. Now create a workflow variable of type string
4. Assign value to this variable as "ABC" + [CurrentItem:ID]
5. Now use "Update list item" action to update the column "Issue ID" with this variable

Hope this helps. I will not be able to provide you screenshots right now.

Comment: can you please adivce on this in more details ? and can i update the ID field from the workflow ?

Comment: No you can not update the ID field using workflow. But you can use the ID field to fulfill your requirement.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please check now.

Comment: ok i got your point but in this case to define the Issue ID , user need to modify the workflow,, but i was thinking of an approach to allow users to add the string such as "ABC" outside the workflow...

Comment: You can Save value "ABC" in some other list. And refer that value while assigning variable. So ID's will be created as ABC-1, ABC-2. Next Time if admin update that value in list Say "XYZ", then Workflow will create value XYZ-3, XYZ-4.

Comment: so i can create a separate list which stores the string "ABC" and then i can read this value from the workflow ,, is this correct ?

Comment: Yes, this is correct

Comment: @P S thanks for the reply,,, but i am not sure if i can inside SharePoint workflow 2010 to read a value from a site collection list based on some query. let say i will create a list with 2 columns ; first column to store the site name while the second column to store the string (ABC). then inside the workflow to search the list based on the current site name and retrieve the string accordingly ,, can u adivce if this is possible ?

Comment: I suggest then you go for development of event receiver or custom workflow.

Comment: so this can not be done using the SharePoint designer ?

Comment: Just replied to this with a (not-as-good-as-the-workflow) solution at http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/160426/create-unique-number-with-id-and-today-age-of-listitem-calculation