# Nomenclature based Unique ID in SharePoint List

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, custom-list, ootb

Hi I am newbie to SharePoint. I need to create a list. challenge is that, when there is a new entry in the list, a unique Id need to be assigned to that entry automatically and the nomenclature of the Unique will be consist of three sets of alphabets (based on the some pre-declared list entries of another list) following by sequential integer.

Looking for an OOB feature to achieve this, and yes I am working with SharePoint Online.

Comment: Similar discussion here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/141922/how-to-force-the-issue-id-inside-issue-tracking-list-to-have-certain-format